# Template rendered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

```
var htmlTemplate = $("#ServiceAndAdDetails").render(result); 
$("#DirectorySection").empty(); 
$("#DirectorySection").html( htmlTemplate );
```

I have used the above coding in the button click event (ajax post success event).
Here `#ServiceAndAdDetails` is the template designed in view page.
`#DirectorySection` is the div.

For me the template is rendering twice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please find the codings here.var htmlTemplate = $("# ServiceAndAdDetails").render(result);
                    $("# DirectorySection").empty();
                    $("# DirectorySection").html( htmlTemplate );

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your problem? Otherwise it is not possible to know what is wrong. Also check the docs and examples such as http://www.jsviews.com/#jsr-quickstart and http://www.jsviews.com/#db.render